# Subspace basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ only with positive values

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

It seems obvious but I didn't find a proof yet:
 Let $U$ be an arbitrary subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Set $m:=\dim{U}$.

Can $U$ be written as $U=\mathrm{span}\{b_1,\dotsc,b_m\}$, $b_j=\begin{pmatrix}b_{i,1}\\\vdots\\b_{i,n}\end{pmatrix}$ with $b_{i,j}\ge0\;\forall i\in\{1,\dotsc,m\}\;\forall j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$?

An equivalent formulation for this question:
$\exists B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1,1}&\cdots &b_{1,n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\b_{m,1}&\cdots &b_{m,n}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}: U=\mathrm{img}(B)$ with $b_{i,j}\ge0\;\forall i\in\{1,\dotsc,m\}\;\forall j\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$?

If yes, can you please give a construction algorithm for a given base $\{u_1,\dotsc,u_m\}$ of $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the line $y=-x$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$. Any basis consists of one vector, which must be of the form $(\alpha,-\alpha)$ for some non-zero $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. For a counter example, consider $\Bbb R^3$ and the 2D subspace $U$ whose normal vector is $(1,1,1)$. Any two non-negative non-zero vectors in $\Bbb R^3_{\ge 0}$ will span a subspace part of which is out of $U$ because $U\cap\Bbb R^3_{\ge 0} = \{0\}$, hence they cannot span $U$.